# Forward all Wireguard traffic through Docker container

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, docker

My understanding of Linux networking is limited. I'd very much appreciate some help!

I want to forward all my incoming Wireguard traffic (interface wgnet0 on the host) through a specific Docker container. The Docker container is designed to inspect the traffic and then forwards the traffic to the internet. IP forwarding is enabled.

The Docker container is attached to a host bridge called docker0.

My specific question is what is the best way to forward all traffic from wgnet0 to that specific container? What command should I use?

Things I've tried so far:

- I've tried using iptables but without much success. For instance, I've tried using iptables to forward traffic directly to the interface of the container's veth, but the packets don't seem to appear within the container. Alternatively, I could redirect the traffic to docker0 but then I have a hard time figuring out the routing table ("route" on linux can only set a gateway based on destination addresses).
- Alternatively, I've tried policy-based routing (PBR) in order to redirect traffic based on source addresss, but it seems hard to debug whenever you get a "next hop" problem.